# Why is this simple Spark program not utlizing multiple cores?

Tags: python, scala, bigdata, apache-spark, multicore

So, I'm running this simple program on a 16 core multicore system. I run it
by issuing the following.

```
spark-submit --master local[*] pi.py
```

And the code of that program is the following.

```
#"""pi.py"""
from pyspark import SparkContext
import random

N = 12500000

def sample(p):
    x, y = random.random(), random.random()
    return 1 if x*x + y*y < 1 else 0

sc = SparkContext("local", "Test App")
count = sc.parallelize(xrange(0, N)).map(sample).reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
print "Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES)
```

When I use top to see CPU
consumption, only 1 core is being utilized. Why is it so? Seconldy, spark
documentation says that the default parallelism is contained in property
*spark.default.parallelism*. How can I read this property from within my
python program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably because the call to sc.parallelize puts all the data into one single partition. You can specify the number of partitions as 2nd argument to parallelize:

```
part = 16
count = sc.parallelize(xrange(N), part).map(sample).reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

Note that this would still generate the 12 millions points with one CPU in the driver and then only spread them out to 16 partitions to perform the reduce step.

A better approach would try to do most of the work after the partitioning: for example the following generates only a tiny array on the driver and then lets each remote task generate the actual random numbers and subsequent PI approximation:

```
part = 16
count = ( sc.parallelize([0] * part, part)
           .flatMap(lambda blah: [sample(p) for p in xrange( N/part)])
           .reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
       )
```

Finally, (because the more lazy we are the better), spark mllib actually comes already with a random data generation which is nicely parallelized, have a look here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/mllib-statistics.html#random-data-generation. So maybe the following is close to what you try to do (not tested => probably not working, but should hopefully be close)

```
count = ( RandomRDDs.uniformRDD(sc, N, part)
        .zip(RandomRDDs.uniformRDD(sc, N, part))
        .filter (lambda (x, y): x*x + y*y < 1)
        .count()
        )
```

Comment: setting partitions didn't work for me. The answer provided by @Ivaylo Petrov did the trick.

Answer (score 28):

As none of the above really worked for me (maybe because I didn't really understand them), here is my two cents.

I was starting my job with `spark-submit program.py` and inside the file I had `sc = SparkContext("local", "Test")`. I tried to verify the number of cores **spark** *sees* with `sc.defaultParallelism`. It turned out that it was 1. When I changed the context initialization to `sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "Test")` it became 16 (the number of cores of my system) and my program was using all the cores.

I am quite new to **spark**, but my understanding is that *local* by default indicates the use of one core and as it is set inside the program, it would overwrite the other settings (for sure in my case it overwrites those from configuration files and environment variables).

Comment: It just works. As a clean solution, IMHO, better than the first answer.

Comment: On a further note, you can replace `*` with the number of cores you wish to use. Leaving it as `*` defaults to the maximum number of local cores. Using just `local` sets it to 1 core.

Comment: Great! but why is it not mentioned anywhere? I mean, it is not even intuitive, right? What kind of syntax is "local[*]"? Anyhow, if this answer wasn't here I would have wasted hours scratching my head

Answer (score 2):

I tried the method mentioned by @Svend, but still does not work.

The following works for me:

Do **NOT** use the `local` url, for example:

`sc = SparkContext("local", "Test App")`.

Use the master URL like this:

`sc = SparkContext("spark://your_spark_master_url:port", "Test App")`

Comment: Or maybe  `sc = SparkContext("Test App")` by default Spark takes the Master. I've tried this on my cloudera installed spark.

Answer (score 1):

To change the CPU core consumption, set the number of cores to be used by the workers in the `spark-env.sh` file in `spark-installation-directory/conf` 
This is done with the `SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES` attribute in spark-env.sh file.
The value is set to 1 by default.

Comment: I don't see any spark-env.sh file but only spark-evn.sh.template file in the spark/conf directory, and every line is commented in that file.

Comment: Thats the one. First rename the file to spark-env.sh. Then uncomment the line and set the value to 16. Such as SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES = 16.

Comment: This same file can be used to set the other configuration properties of the Spark cluster by un-commenting the required lines.

Comment: It is still using only 1 core. Is it possible to set this value at runtime, by modifiying it inside the code. I use python to write the program.

Comment: Yes. You can refer to this link : http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/configuration.html. spark.default.parallelism and other parameters can be set at run time using the spark context.