# Equivalent of flatMap in Python's concurrency framework

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a piece of code like this:

```
for x in range(10):
    for v in f(x):
        print(v)
```

I would like to parallelize it, so I might do

```
ex = ProcessPollExecutor()
for vs in ex.map(f, range(10)):
    for v in vs:
        print(v)
```

However, `f` is a generator, so the above code doesn't really work.
I can change `f` to return a list, but this list will be too big to fit in memory.

Ideally I would like something like `flatMap` in pyspark.
However using pyspark directly like `sc.parallelize(range(10)).flatMap(f).toLocalIterator()`
 doesn't seem to work. At least I can't get it to utilize more than one processor when the initial list is that short.
(I've tried all of the stuff in [Why is this simple Spark program not utlizing multiple cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26828987/205521) with no luck.)

I can probably roll something by myself using queues, but I wonder if there is an intended way to parallelize such code in the Python concurrency framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coding my own small library using `multiprocessing`: [PyStreams](https://github.com/thomasahle/pystreams).

It has pretty efficient flapmap support via buffering, and supports other Spark like features like this:

```
>>> sentences = ["a word is a word", "all words are words"]
>>> (Stream(sentences)
...           .flatmap(lambda sentence: sentence.split())
...           .chunk_by_key(lambda x: hash(x) % 10)
...           .reduce_once(lambda chunk: len(set(chunk)))
...           .sum())
6
```